# complex analysis, proof, why does this follow from uniform continuity

Tags: complex-analysis

There is something in the this proof I dont understand. First the book makes a definition, and then it has a theorem it proves. I have marked in red what I dont understand. After the picture I will explain more in detail what I dont understand.

[image]

From what I see we can look at $\gamma$, as $\gamma(s,t)$. Since our domain is compact, I understand that since it is continuous, it is also uniformly continuous. This gives that for an epsilon there is a delta such that:

$|\gamma(s_1,t_1)-\gamma(s_2,t_2)|<\epsilon$, if $|(s_1,t_1)-(s_2,t_2)|< \delta$. This is what I get from uniform continuity, how do they get the statement they get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|s_1 - s_2| \leq |(s_1,t_1) - (s_2,t_2)|$

Comment: To be of help in this question you need an inequality which goes the opposite way.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks, good point!

Comment: And I guess it follows from $\sqrt{(s_2-s_1)^2}\le\sqrt{(s_2-s_1)^2+(t_2-t_2)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Given an $\epsilon>0$ you can find a $\delta>0$ such that
$$\bigl|(s_1,t_1)-(s_2,t_2)\bigr|< \delta\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \bigl|\gamma(s_1,t_1)-\gamma(s_2,t_2)\bigr|<\epsilon\ .$$
It follows that
$$|s_1-s_2|< \delta\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad  \bigl|\gamma(s_1,t)-\gamma(s_2,t)\bigr|<\epsilon\quad\forall \ t\in[a,b]\ ,$$
and this implies
$$\bigl|s_1-s_2\bigr|< \delta\quad\Rightarrow\quad \sup_{t\in[a,b]}\bigl|\gamma(s_1,t)-\gamma(s_2,t)\bigr|\leq\epsilon\ .$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!